# OAuth2 Auth Code flow: logged in to Spring boot app. Require to obtain access token again using auth code flow from the backend spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

The application setup is as this:  the app --> broker keyclock[external IDP], this is first keyclock ----> IDP Provider[Internal IDP], this another keyclock

In case the user directly logged in the app using IDP Provider using authorization code flow, I need to initiate a call from the spring boot class to the broker keyclock to get access token using the authorization code flow again, this access token will be used to access API which is accessible from the token issued from  this keyclock.

Please suggest spring boot API which can be used to achieve this. Below is the code snippet which not working

```
AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
         resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        resource.setClientId("clientId");
        resource.setClientSecret("clientSecret");
        resource.setAccessTokenUri("url/protocol/openid-connect/token");
        resource.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri("redirectURl");
        resource.setGrantType(Constant.GRANT_TYPE_CODE);
```